# Function that takes a value and return a percentage

Tags: functions, percentages

I can't figure out how to create a function that takes as input a value between 0 and 180 and returns a percentage:

For a value 1 for example : 176 return 100%

For a value 2 for example : 86 return 0%

and return a big value of percentage if the value is near value 1 for example:  176

and return a small value of percentage if the value is near value 2 for example:  86

I created the image below to simplify my problem :

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcdhC.png)

Edit 1 : The input of the function is always between 0 and 180.

Comment: You have not defined your function precisely enough to construct one.  How big is big?  How close is close?  Do you want a linear function from $176$ to $86$?  Can the argument of the function be outside the range?

Comment: Just a linear function, No the argument are always in the range

Answer (score 0):

If the first value is $a$ and the second is $b$, you have 
$$f(x)=\frac {x-b}{a-b}\cdot 100\%$$